# Ninja Error : rebuilding 'build.ninja': dependency cycle using Qt6 LinguistTools Cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, ninja

I'm trying to use the linguistic module of Qt6 and I have this error when building my app :

```bash
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': dependency cycle: src/arcadia_fr.qm -> src/.lupdate/arcadia_fr.ts.stamp -> src/arcadia_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp -> src/arcadia_fr.qm
```

I'm building a c++ qt6 app using CMake. Here is the part of my `CMakeLists.txt` building the `.qm` files for the translations :

```
qt_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} resources/translations/arcadia_fr.ts)
configure_file(${QM_FILES} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/resources/translations COPYONLY)

qt_add_resources(RESOURCES resources/resources.qrc)

# create executable
qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_PATHS} ${INCLUDE_PATHS} ${UIS} ${QM_FILES})
```

And here is my project structure :

```
arcadia (my project name)
+-- CMakeLists.txt (Call the second CMakeLists.txt
+-- src/
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt 
|   +-- resources/
|       +-- translations/ (my qm files are here)
|           +-- arcadia_fr.ts
|           +-- arcadia_fr.qm
|       +-- resources.qrc (contains .qm in the translations folder)
```